# Using jQuery on external loaded DataTable after AJAX refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatable

So I have on my page a div with id="machine-content", which I use to display various info about my machines. Mainly, I display information in tables. I am trying to use DataTables (https://datatables.net/), but I have problem initializing the table. After click on action (i.e. "show me repairs", "show me workhours"), I load a table element from external html and fill it with data through AJAX according to chosen action. 
So here's how my files look.

In index.php (jquery and datatables are loaded in head):

```
<script src="data.js"></script>

...
<div id="machine-content" class="col-md-9" style="float:right">
</div>  
...
```

External html is super simple:

```
<h1 id="machine-content-h1"></h1>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>
```

I then have data.js that controls index.php. There, I handle clicks to actions and loading of table through AJAX. All the data is loaded correctly but when I want to initialize a DataTable (to get search field, paging, etc.) it doesnt work. As far as I know, I have to initialise it after the data is loaded, anyway I also tried initialising it before. Here is data.js:

```
//EXAMPLE of handling chosen action with button click
//I TRIED putting //I TRIED putting $.('#example').DataTable(); HERE
//wrapped in $(document).ready

$('#arentals').click(function(){
            $( '#machine-content' ).load("/gui/machines/machines/templates/table.html", function() {
                load_service_table("RENTALS");      
     });
}); 

function load_service_table(action){
    var action_url;

    switch(action) {
        case 'REPAIRS':
            action_url='/gui/machines/machines/show_services.php';
            break;
        case 'RENTALS':
            action_url='/gui/machines/machines/show_rentals.php';
            break;
        case 'REVENUES':
            action_url='/gui/machines/machines/show_revenues.php';
            break;
        default:
            action_url='/gui/machines/machines/show_hours.php';
    }

    $.ajax({
            url: action_url,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "html",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                //I TRIED putting $.('#example').DataTable(); HERE
                $( '#machine-content-h1' ).text(action);
                $( '#example' ).html(data); 
                //I ALSO TRIED putting $.('#example').DataTable(); HERE
            }       
    });
    //AND HERE
}
```

PHP functions are simple and in AJAX return only head and body elements of table, so I guess there is no problem.
So my question is: How can I initialize this thing? I mean, if I am able to set html to #example in AJAX success function, why can't I initialise the same element there? Any help would be deeply appreciated.

**EDIT**
I always get this error:
jquery.dataTables.min.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

**SOLUTION**

I only added $('#machine-content').find('#example').DataTable(); to AJAX success function which now looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: action_url,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "html",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {

                $( '#machine-content-h1' ).text(action);
                $( '#example' ).html(data); 
                $('#machine-content').find('#example').DataTable();
            }       
    });
```

Comment: datatable has a build in ajax method

Answer (score 0):

datatable has a build-in ajax method

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    ajax: '/api/myData'
} );
```

https://datatables.net/manual/ajax#Loading-data

or use:

```
$('#machine-content').find('.table').DataTable();
```

Comment: I see. But still, is there a solution to my way? I mean I have all my php functions written in a way that they output html and I would like to change all that only as a last resort. Thanks for the info though!

Comment: why are you putting a dot after the $ in the commented code?

Comment: what role does the external html have, why do you call it external?

Comment: Ups, thats a typo, my bad. It's external because I load it from another html file via jquery. I want to have it in another file because I need a table only if a user wants to see let's say repairs of a machine which are shown in table. E.g. I also have an input form that I load in the same div when user wants to add a new machine. Thats why I dont want table in index.php

Comment: that means you do 2 ajax one for the table element and one for the content of it?

Comment: Yes. That's a bit inefficient, I know, but it should still work. First ajax loads only table (see external html above), and second fills in the data (call to php return table elements in html).

Comment: try it with a class `$('#machine-content').find('.table')..DataTable();`

Comment: Hey man that did it! I put  $('#machine-content').find('#example')..DataTable(); in AJAX's succes function at the end and it works now! I don't know why it was necessary to use find() since $('#example').html(data); works fine but hey it works now. Many thanks. You can wirte a reply with this and I'll mark it as a solution

Comment: @GregorStopar you need to use find because the element is dynamically added by the first ajax

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is older so probably of no help to you now but for anyone else who comes across this.

Something like the following should work:

```
var adminUsers = {

list: () => {

var action = 'list_users';
var url = base_url+'index.php/admin/users/io';
var data = { }

var response = ajaxRequest.post(action, url, data);

response.then(
    function(obj){
        var data = JSON.parse(obj);
        console.log(data);
        //console.log(data.data.result);
        $.each(data.data, function(i,e){
            var html = '';
            html = html + '<tr>';
            html = html + '<td>'+e.id+'</td>';
            html = html + '<td>'+e.username+'</td>';
            html = html + '<td>'+e.first_name+'&nbsp;'+e.last_name+'</td>';
            html = html + '<td>'+e.status+'</td>';
            html = html + '<td>'+e.locked+'</td>';
            html = html + '<td>'+e.uuid+'</td>';
            html = html + '</tr>';
            $('#users-list tbody').append(html);
        });

        $('#users-list').DataTable(adminUsers.dataTable());
    },
    function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        ajaxRequest.error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    });
},
dataTable: () => {
var config = {
        initComplete : function() {

            $("#users-list_filter").detach().appendTo('#search');
            $("#users-list_length").detach().appendTo('#display_length');
            $("#users-list_length").attr('style', 'margin-right:10px;');
            $("#users-list_filter input").addClass('form-control');

        },
        language: { 
            search: "",
            searchPlaceholder: 'Search...' 
        }
    }        

    return config;
}

};
```